# Unity 4.0.0f7 custom tab not visible/available

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 4.0.0f7 for a 2D game, and it has to use a C# script to convert all the textures to the desired mode for sprite manager 2.

I can't see the custom tab. All I see is

> File  | Edit | Assets | GameObject | Terrain | Window | Help

How can I get the custom tab to be available?

Answer (score 1):

For a custom menu item to appear your script will need to import the UnityEditor namespace and use the appropriate [MenuItem](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) before the function you want to get called. Something more or less like:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

//Let's for example give a custom component some fancy menu item
public class WonderfulThingDoer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [MenuItem("MyTab/MyThingToDo")]
    static void MyWonderfulThingToDo()
    {
        //insert amazing stuff here
    }
}
```

Given that you say you already have a script available, I would assume it's in your project. If it's an editor extension however, it has to be in an Editor folder. This can be a direct sub-folder of the Assets folder, or of any other (sub-)folder within Assets. So have a look at that first.